# How to see memory map of class in c++ using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a simple class. Created a object of class, Now I wanted to access class members using pointer to object. 
I know we have 2 ways available: ptr->member and (*ptr).member 
What i want? As in C, we do not need to give struct member name, just by incrementing pointer we can access struct members. Same as that starting from member-1, increment pointer, access member-2 so on.

I know: This code thinks << is overloaded operator and does not compile. But How to print class members using dereference & pointer increment without giving member name and using ->, (*).

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class base{
public:
    int a
    char b;
    base(){a=10;b='a';}
    void test(base *ptr){
        cout<<"Member-1="<<(*ptr);
        ptr++;
        cout<<"Member-2="<<(*ptr);
    }
};
int main(){
    base objB;
    objB.test(&objB);
}
```

Comment: Fix your code formatting please!

Comment: `ptr++` doesn't give you the next member, it moves to the next `base`. Just like it does in C.

Comment: What du you want to archieve with this?

Comment: As in C, you *do* need to give the struct member name. You may have misunderstood some C code.

Answer (score 0):

If you just increment your pointer it can lead to undefined behaviour!
You can't guarantee that after one class or struct the next one is right next to it located, so the pointer incrementation here is pretty dangerous. Same goes for the variables inside your class.
You are using classes, so you should access the members via:

```
cout<<"Member-1="<<ptr->a;
cout<<"Member-2="<<ptr->b;
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
   class MyClass{
     int i;
     char c;
    public:
       MyClass(int i , char c){
            this->i = i;
            this->c = c;
       }
       friend const ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const MyClass& obj) 
         {
            out << obj.i <<endl;
            out << obj.c;
         return out;
         }
  };  
 int main(){
    MyClass mClass(50,'C');

   cout << mClass;
   return 0;
 }
```

Would you please fix all the syntax errors in your code first?
I don't think its possible to iterate through member variables of a class object...but you can iterate through an array of objects.

if at all you would like to print the values of the member variables without using objectName->memberVar or (*objectName).memberVar, you can overload "<<" then perform the insertion operation inside the method that overloads the stream insertion operator.